# File type field clipping information in Windows 11

Tags: html, windows, forms

Recently I've been having a weird experience with Windows 11 and file field. When I select the file with very long names, their names are cut to the point of reducing the file extension, for example, from .html to .htm.

Does anyone know what this can be?[image]

I've tried updating my code, my OS and my drivers and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking really, really hard, I landed on a Microsoft forum where a user was having the same problem. On Windows we have a **260/255 character limit for filenames this includes all the path that make up the file**. Since the name/path is long the name is cut off at the time the file is selected.